# Linq to Entities query to select latest, distinct records

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, umbraco

I'm trying to retrieve records ordered by a `DateTime` with Linq to entities, but I need them as distinct records as well.

My table design looks like this:

[image]

Where `blogItemNodeId` is an Umbraco CMS node (the blog item node to which a comment can be created)

The requirement is that a list of blog items can be sorted by how many comments they have. So I need to get the latest comments distinct by `blogItemNodeId` to display those blog items.

My current linq query looks like this:

```
var distinctComments = (from c in ctx.BlogComments
                        orderby c.date
                        group c by c.blogItemNodeId
                        into uniqueRecords
                        select uniqueRecords.FirstOrDefault());
```

The problem with this query is that it finds the first (hence `FirstOrDefault()`) record with distinct `blogItemNodeId` where it should find the one which is newest of all comments with the same `blogItemNodeId`.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? :-)

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT**

I managed to get it to work by doing this:

```
var allComments = (from c in ctx.BlogComments
                   orderby c.date descending
                   select c).ToList();

var distinctComments = allComments.GroupBy(x => x.blogItemNodeId).Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

But then I have to get *all* the comments before doing the group which is not very elegant nor performant.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just found this "Question".  You should have "Answered your own question with the edit" section the clarify that you found the answer.  This helps others (and adds to your rep points!).

Answer (score 2):

You could combine both the orderBy statement and the GroupBy statement into one single statement like this:

```
var distinctComments = ctx.BlogComments.OrderBy(c => c.date)
                        .GroupBy(x => x.blogItemNodeId)
                        .Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

If the performance is bad, you could cache your DataContext in the HttpCache through a Singleton. See [this blogpost](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/26479-Linq-to-Umbraco-singleton-datacontext-and-document-updates) for an example. This is based on the Umbraco DataContext but can be easily modified for use with another type of context.